Por que desde la api de mercadolibre no aparecen las opiniones de un producto, cuando desde la pagina si se ven
Por ejemplo para esta publicacion aparecen las calificaiciones y entonces para buscar las optiniones necesito el id del item, que lo consegui a traves de la api de productos de catalogo y luego utlilicé la api de opiniones y envie los parametros pero me deuelve 0 y no se que hacer aqui



